# Given the exponential equation $4^x = 64$, what is the logarithmic form of the equation in base $10$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Given the exponential equation $4^x = 64$, what is the logarithmic form of the equation in base $10$?

Would it be $\frac{\log_{10}64}{\log_{10}4}$?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with $4^x = 64$, take a logarithm on both sides to get

$$\log_{10} 4^x = \log_{10} 64 \implies x \log_{10} 4 = \log_{10} 64 \implies x = \frac{\log_{10} 64}{\log_{10} 4}$$